# Using python imaplib to "delete" an email from Gmail?

Tags: python, email, imap

Can you delete emails with imaplib?  If so how?

Comment: as of mid-2012 none of the answers below work unless you first adjust the default imap settings -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988583/problem-deleting-emails-in-gmail-using-imaplib

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [store](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html?highlight=imaplib#imaplib.IMAP4.store) method (of the `IMAP4` object representing your connection) to set the `r'\Deleted'` flag on the message number you want to delete, as the example in the docs show; then the [expunge](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html?highlight=imaplib#imaplib.IMAP4.expunge) method to actually perform all deletions so marked.

Gmail's implementation of IMAP has subtly different semantics, by default, but if you want you can [tweak](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/10/new-in-labs-advanced-imap-controls.html) it to behave much more like a traditional IMAP implementation (where the above sequence works) -- basically you have to enable the "Advanced IMAP Controls" lab, then follow the instructions at the URL I gave to get exactly the IMAP semantics you desire (physically deleting rather than archiving "deleted" mails, waiting or not for `expunge`, and so forth).

Answer (score 19):

Deleting an email over IMAP is performed in two phases:

- mark one or more items for deletion: `imap.store(msg_no, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')`
- expunge the mailbox: `imap.expunge()`

(`imap` is your `IMAP4` object)

Comment: This is removing my email from my inbox. But if I search gmail for the item it is still there. Any idea?
Using this specifically with gmail.
Any difference depending on python version or gmail settings?

Comment: It'll move the email to your Bin label, which is cleaned up automatically every 30 days.

Answer (score 11):

```
imap.uid('STORE', list_of_msgno , '+FLAGS', '(\Deleted)')  
imap.expunge()
```

i.e

```
imap.uid('STORE', '2, 4, 9, 12' , '+FLAGS', '(\Deleted)')
```

Here `(2, 4, 9, 12)` are `uid` of the messages which are going to be deleted.

Comment: is UID same as what we get from imap.search?