# Problem deleting emails in gmail using imaplib

Tags: python, gmail, imap, imaplib, gmail-imap

I try to remove message from inbox folder and all alright, but when i switched to All Mail folder the removing does not work. `expunge()` method returns `('OK', [None])` and message was not removed:

```
>>>import imaplib
>>>server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com','993')
>>>server.login('likvidator89@gmail.com','Password')
>>>server.select('inbox')
>>>for i in server.search(None,'all')[1][0].split():
...    print i+"\n"+server.fetch(i,'(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (Subject)])')[1][0][1]
...
#  that how i know what UID hame my message? I select by subject
#....
#28
#Subject: 1 Question Has 1 Answer - Stack Overflow
#
#
#29
#Subject: 2222222222
#...
>>>server.store(29,'+FLAGS','\\Deleted')
#('OK', ['29 (FLAGS (\\Seen \\Deleted))'])
>>>server.expunge()
#('OK', ['29'])
>>> server.select('[Gmail]/All Mail')
('OK', ['47'])
>>> for i in server.search(None,'all')[1][0].split():
...  print i+"\n"+server.fetch(i,'(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (Subject)])')[1][0][1]
... 
#....
#
#46
#Subject: 2222222222
#
#
#47
#Subject: 3333333333333333
#
#....
>>> server.store(47,'+FLAGS','\\Deleted')
('OK', ['47 (FLAGS (\\Seen \\Deleted))'])
>>> server.expunge()
('OK', [None])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it says on the [gmail blog site](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/10/new-in-labs-advanced-imap-controls.html), Google's implementation of IMAP is a bit different. When you follow the instructions for getting more usual semantics, does it help?

> There are also some more obscure
>   options for those of you who want to
>   make Gmail's IMAP work more like
>   traditional IMAP providers: you can
>   turn off auto-expunge or trash
>   messages when they're no longer
>   visible through IMAP.
>
> The IMAP protocol allows messages to
>   be marked for deletion, a sort of
>   limbo state where a message is still
>   present in the folder but slated to be
>   deleted the next time the folder is
>   expunged. In our standard IMAP
>   implementation, when you mark a
>   message as deleted, Gmail doesn't let
>   it linger in that state -- it deletes
>   (or auto-expunges) it from the folder
>   right away. If you want the two-stage
>   delete process, after you've enabled
>   this Lab, just select 'Do not
>   automatically expunge messages' under
>   the 'Forwarding and POP/IMAP' tab in
>   Settings.
>
> Similarly, most IMAP systems don't
>   share Gmail's concept of archiving
>   messages (sending messages to the
>   [Gmail]/All Mail folder rather than
>   [Gmail]/Trash). If you'd prefer that
>   deleted messages not remaining in any
>   other visible IMAP folders are sent to
>   [Gmail]/Trash instead, Advanced IMAP
>   Controls lets you set your preferences
>   this way. In the 'IMAP Access:'
>   section of the 'Forwarding and
>   POP/IMAP' tab, find the 'When a
>   message is deleted from the last
>   visible IMAP folder:' option. Select
>   'Move the message to the Gmail Trash.'
>   If you want to take it one step
>   further, you can select 'Immediately
>   delete the message forever.'

Answer (score 17):

it moves all the mail in a given gmail label to the gmail Trash

```
#!usr/bin/python
import email, imaplib

user = 'xxx'
pwd = 'xxx'

m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login(user,pwd)

m.select("some_gmail_label")
m.store("1:*",'+X-GM-LABELS', '\\Trash')

m.expunge() # should be useless, but gmail server says it is ok
```

Remember to refresh your gmail interface cause it has cache

Comment: Great suggestion.  Where are the docs on this usage of m.store()?

Comment: @jml: quoting from the [IMAP spec, RFC 3501](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501) : `* represents the largest number in use`

Answer (score 6):

With [Gmail advanced IMAP controls](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/10/advanced-imap-settings-for-gmail.html) you can set what happens to messages when you delete them over IMAP.

Just enable "Advanced IMAP Controls" in Gmail Labs. The settings page will look like this:

[image: settings]

Then when you mark a message as deleted and expunge as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777264/using-python-imaplib-to-delete-an-email-from-gmail/1777290#1777290) it will be moved to the bin, permanently deleted, or archived to "All Mail" depending on what setting you selected.

Comment: I have tried your approach but when I delete a message the message will have an INBOX label while if we delete from gmail itself the message will not have any label.

Comment: I know this is a really old thread, but to help anyone else with Rahul's problem above, you just need to remove the "inbox label" first, before you add the trash label. i.e. `imap.store(num, '-X-GM-LABELS', '\\Inbox')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one that works with Gmail and does it very quickly (without store in a for loop).  Tailor this as you wish, but the idea is all there on how to use select/search and then perform a store, or just select on its own for all items with a specific label/folder:

```
#!/bin/python

import datetime
import imaplib

m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")  # server to connect to
print "Connecting to mailbox..."
m.login('gmail@your_gmail.com', 'your_password')

print m.select('[Gmail]/All Mail')  # required to perform search, m.list() for all lables, '[Gmail]/Sent Mail'
before_date = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(365)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")  # date string, 04-Jan-2013
typ, data = m.search(None, '(BEFORE {0})'.format(before_date))  # search pointer for msgs before before_date

if data != ['']:  # if not empty list means messages exist
    no_msgs = data[0].split()[-1]  # last msg id in the list
    print "To be removed:\t", no_msgs, "messages found with date before", before_date
    m.store("1:{0}".format(no_msgs), '+X-GM-LABELS', '\\Trash')  # move to trash
    print "Deleted {0} messages. Closing connection & logging out.".format(no_msgs)
else:
    print "Nothing to remove."

#This block empties trash, remove if you want to keep, Gmail auto purges trash after 30 days.
print("Emptying Trash & Expunge...")
m.select('[Gmail]/Trash')  # select all trash
m.store("1:*", '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')  #Flag all Trash as Deleted
m.expunge()  # not need if auto-expunge enabled

print("Done. Closing connection & logging out.")
m.close()
m.logout()
print "All Done."
```